# RegEx - How to allow whitespace only if there's other characters

Tags: java, regex

I have the following RegEx:

`(\\+)([\\w\\d]+)(=)(.+)`

This should allow:

+[CharWords][Digits]=[Everything]

The second part (after the '=') should not allow whitespace characters to be there, unless there is a digit or word char.

I can't seem to achieve this. How can such a RegEx be built.

EDIT:

Here are valid examples:

```
+Valid123=Valid123
+123Valid=Valid 123
+Valid=This is Valid 14
+Valid=(This is Valid)
```

My question is how to avoid this:

Not Valid=whitespace

Comment: You should give examples of strings that are positive matches and negative matches to help users with testing to see if they match your question correctly.

Comment: Please clarify this statement: `should not allow whitespace characters to be there, unless there is a digit or word char`.

Comment: Do you mean this: `String str = " abcde = "` should go to `String str = " abcde ="` or to `"abcde ="`? for the second, use `str = str.trim();` [`String.trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

Comment: @Walls

I edited with the valid examples.

Comment: @Asdf: Provide some invalid examples as well, like what is not allowed after `=` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `\w` stands for "word character", usually `[A-Za-z0-9_]` so you don't need to add `\d` inside your class.
2. > ...not allow whitespace characters to be there, unless there is a digit
   >   or word char.

   try maybe this way ...=`(\\s*\\w+)+`, -> `\\s*\\w+` will accept only strings that have `zero or more whitespaces at start` and `1 or more characters at end` like `"a"`, `" ab"`, `"  c"`. `(\\s*\\w+)+` will make regex to accept 1 or more of such tokens.

Comment: This worked, I'm not sure what this means though.

Does it means that you set a limit to 0 if the whitespace is alone `\\s*` but if it's in a group `(\\s*\\w+)+` it should be taken into account?

Comment: Depending on the nature of your input, it's worth noting that the group \\s does not include non-breaking-spaces (0xA0).  You may want to add it if you expect to encounter non-breaking spaces in your input.

Comment: Pls note that will not allow: `+abd12=1.5` Not sure if that is needed or not.

Comment: @anubhava

I solved by doing it like this: `(\\+)([0-9A-z]+)(=)(\\s*\\S+)+`

Got this idea after reading the `(\\s*\\S+\\s*)` part of your RegEx.

Answer (score 2):

Following regex should work for you:

```
^(\\+)(\\w+)(=)(\\s*\\S+\\s*)+$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `^\+[\w\d]+=(\S+.*)$`.

This matches your first piece, but the key is in the part after the `=`.  It requires at least one NON space followed by anything (which allows spaces after the initial match of a not space), so `+word123= testing` would fail where `+word123=testing 123` would pass.  If the first char. after the `=` is a space, it isn't allowed.  If the first char. is anything but a space, it should allow spaces and anything else after the fact.

If you need to change what can come after the initial word/digit/etc after the `=`, you simply insert a more complex set of rules in a `()` in place of the `.` in `(\S+.*)`.

The testing can be seen [here](http://rubular.com/r/w2FcroyIGl).  You may have to tweak it a bit (escape java slashes, etc).